# Repeated Permutations

Tags: statistics, permutations, combinations

In school we have been studying combinations and permutations, and in a programming assignment I was testing points on a coordinate plane. Testing all integer points surrounding the point (0,0) you obviously end up with 9 different permutations.

(0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1) (0,-1) (-1,0) (-1,-1) (1,-1) (-1,1)

I was trying to model this using the combination and permutation formulas we learned in class, and I arrive at an answer of 30 different permutations or 5 combinations.

P = (6!/4!) = 30
C = 30/3! = 5

How would I take into account combinations that are not equivalent when reversed and disregard those that are?

I apologize if this questions has been answered elsewhere, if nothing else I guess i'm asking what I should search to find what i'm looking for.

Comment: Where are you getting that 6 from in your calculation?

Comment: I had initially tried to use a set of 6 (0,0,1,1,-1,-1) to account for cases like (0,0), but quickly realized that was no the right path to go down. I then removed the description and forgot to change those numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I now realize that if an object in the set can be used more than once then you can just multiply how many objects you are choosing from the number of choices  you have.

Comment: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algebra/APR2/LpermRep.htm may also be useful for background here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take the simpler approach of noting that there are 3 possibilities for each co-ordinate and 2 positions so the answer is $3\times3=9$ for a computational answer.

Now, if you want to look at them without order mattering, generally you'd break this down into cases and sum over those:

3 cases of the same digit repeated: (0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1)

If the digits don't repeat then it would be 3 choices for the first and 2 for the second value but there is a division by 2 because of double counting that leads to 3 possibilities: (0,1), (0,-1), and (1,-1).

The key is to consider whether order matters and is duplication allowed or not.